# Set the default select option to be the first item in the list

Tags: knockout.js

Using the [knockout cart demo](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html) on the knockout examples page, does anyone know how to change it so that the "product" select is always defaulted to the first product in the select box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using the `options` binding, other bindings are also recognized.  In the example provided, `optionsText` is a binding which determines which property of each object will be displayed as the text.  The other property used in the example is the `optionsCaption`.  This binding sets the initial text to be shown for the select box when nothing is selected.

If you want to change it so the select boxes start with a the first value in the list, just remove the `optionsCaption` binding.  Assuming the observable bound to the `value` binding is not set, it will default to the first item in the array.

change this:

```html
<select data-bind="options: sampleProductCategories,
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   optionsCaption: 'Select...',
                   value: category"></select>
```

to this:

```html
<select data-bind="options: sampleProductCategories,
                   optionsText: 'name',
                   value: category"></select>
```